# Change in object inside a list is not refreshing the subcomponents

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following flutter code. For some reason in the below code `_cartProducts[index].quantity = state.quantity` is correctly assigned but `ProductListItem` is not getting updated. Any ideas ?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
     CartBloc cartBloc;
     TrendingProductBloc trendingProductBloc;
     List<CartEntry> _cartProducts = [];
     List<Product> trendingProducts;

     
     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       cartBloc = BlocProvider.of<CartBloc>(context);
       trendingProductBloc = BlocProvider.of<TrendingProductBloc>(context);

       cartBloc.add(GetCartProductsEvent()); // load cart items
       trendingProductBloc.add(LoadTrendingProductsEvent()); // load trending items

       cartBloc.stream.listen((state) {
          if (state is GetCartProductsCompletedState) { //triggered when load cart entries
             _cartProducts = state.cartProductsList;
          }

          if (state is UpdateQuantityCompletedState) { //triggered when update quantity of an cart item
             int index = _cartProducts.indexWhere((item) => item.product.id == state.productId);
             _cartProducts[index].quantity = state.quantity; // This has no effect 
          }
        });
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       super.build(context);
       .....
       Container(
          height: 280.0,
          child: BlocBuilder(
             bloc: trendingProductBloc,
                 builder: (context, state) {
                     if (state is LoadTrendingProductsCompletedState) {
                        trendingProducts = state.productList;
                        return ListView.separated(
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ProductListItem( // This has no effect when a list item quantity changes.
                                cartProducts: _cartProducts,
                                product: trendingProducts[index],
                                cartBloc: cartBloc,
                                currentUser: currentUser,
                              );
                            },
                        )
                     }
                 },
          ),
        ),
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how your bloc is work, but i think you need update screen, by adding event which update new state. simplest way is add `setState` after change the quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the `ProductListItem` only when the state `LoadTrendingProductsCompletedState` is fired. Therefore, if you want to update the `ProductListItem` when the number of items in the cart changes, you need to listen to the `UpdateQuantityCompletedState` state too. But keep in mind that you feed the `BlocBuilder` with the `trendingProductBloc` bloc and the `UpdateQuantityCompletedState` belongs to the `cartBloc` bloc, which is a different bloc. So, you have two options:

1. Nest two `BlocBuilders` (one for every bloc)
2. Merge the two blocs and use only one `BlocBuilder`

If you choose the first option because you want to have two separated blocs, do something like this (Note the variables' name for the states of the different blocs are not the same to avoid using only the states of the inner `BlocBuilder`):

```js
...
@override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       super.build(context);
       .....
       Container(
          height: 280.0,
          child: BlocBuilder(
             bloc: cartBloc,
                 builder: (context, cartState) {
                 return BlocBuilder(
                   bloc: trendingProductBloc,
                       builder: (context, trendingProductState) {
                           // Here you consider states from different blocs.
                           if (cartState is UpdateQuantityCompletedState || trendingProductState is LoadTrendingProductsCompletedState) {
                              trendingProducts = state.productList;
                              return ListView.separated(
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return ProductListItem(
                                      cartProducts: _cartProducts,
                                      product: trendingProducts[index],
                                      cartBloc: cartBloc,
                                      currentUser: currentUser,
                                    );
                                  },
                              )
                           }
                       },
                    );
                 },
            ),
        ),
     }
...
```